# Test whether a method is defined

Tags: scala, reflection

I use scala reflection to get information on a trait defined in my *Model* Class.
I can easily get the members of this class doing this:

```
ru.runtimeMirror(myClassLoader).staticClass("model.Model").typeSignature.members
```

but how to know whether these members are defined or not, ie if they have an implementation or not ?

Answer (score 8):

Wow that's an oversight! I've submitted a pull request targetting 2.11.0 (https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/2612) that adds `Symbol.isAbstract`.

Since this is a new API, due to compatibility restrictions it cannot make it into 2.10.x, so in the meanwhile please use the following workaround:

```
00:01 ~/Projects/210x (2.10.x)$ scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.3-20130527-133534-9b310bc906 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_45).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> trait C { def foo: Int; def bar = 2 }
defined trait C

scala> val foo = typeOf[C].declarations.toList.apply(1)
foo: reflect.runtime.universe.Symbol = method foo

scala> val bar = typeOf[C].declarations.toList.apply(2)
bar: reflect.runtime.universe.Symbol = method bar

scala> def isDeferred(sym: Symbol) = sym
         .asInstanceOf[scala.reflect.internal.Symbols#Symbol]
         .hasFlag(scala.reflect.internal.Flags.DEFERRED)
isDeferred: (sym: reflect.runtime.universe.Symbol)Boolean

scala> isDeferred(foo)
res2: Boolean = true

scala> isDeferred(bar)
res3: Boolean = false
```